# Passing a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

i'm having trouble with the following jquery code

```
$this->registerJs(
    'jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".member").on("change",function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        // alert(id);
        var n = $(this).val();
        // alert(n);
        $.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation','id'=>'+id'])
            .'&name="+id) 


        });

      });'
);
```

i want the ajax link to be like this `http://192.168.1.4/~user/church/backend/web/death/stl_set_relation?id=20&name=1`

but with my code i'm not able to pass value of id correctly. 
what my code creates is the following url

```
http://192.168.1.4/~user/church/backend/web/death/stl_set_relation?id=%2Bid&name=20
```

i also tried like this

```
$.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation','id'=>'"+id"'])
                .'&name="+id)
```

but it didn't give me the desired result

how can i pass the value of id correctly?

Comment: `%2B = +` so  the end of your link is encoded '+id' turns into `%2Bid`  since your'e using quotes, don't include the + inside the quotes. try: `'+"id"'`

Comment: i tried and i got this url http://192.168.1.4/~user/church/backend/web/death/stl_set_relation?id=%2B%22id%22&name=20

Comment: That's not what I said to do. I'm talking about the id. The code you just posted in the previous comment doesn't even have a + nor does it have double quotes.

Comment: i tried as u said like this $.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation','id'=>'+"id"'])
      .'&name="+id)

Comment: Does it matter if the you swap the order? Nevermind it looks like it does...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96756/discussion-between-bloodhound-and-zer00ne).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using following code

```
$.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation'])
                .'?id="+id+"&relation="+n)
```

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate URLs like that. Look at @GAMITG's example. It's so much cleaner to pass your `id` and `relation` variables as POST data: `$.post( "'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation']).'", { id: id, relation: n })`

Comment: i got this solution before @gamitg posted his answer. Yes his answer is the cleaner one.

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying it's much cleaner to pass your data as an object (`{id: id, relation: n}`) than to append it to the URL.

Comment: To be fair, using `Url::toRoute` instead of `createUrl` solves nothing. The significant part is passing data as object.

Answer (score 2):

try like this may be it will work..

```
$.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation','id'=>'"+id+"'])
        .'&name="+n);
```

Comment: it gave me an error syntax error, unexpected 'death' (T_STRING)

Comment: it didn't work i got redirected to this url 192.168.1.4/~user/church/backend/web/death/stl_set_relation?id=%22%2Bid%2B%22&name=22

Comment: you try exactly  like this?.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in another way that is by using `yii\helpers\Url` class.

For example :

```
$this->registerJs(
    'jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".member").on("change",function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            // alert(id);
            var n = $(this).val();
            // alert(n);
            $.post( "'.Url::toRoute('death/stl_set_relation').'", { id: id, name: id });
        });
     });'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

`$.post("<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl([\'death/stl_set_relation\']) ?>?id="+id+"&name="+id)`.

Whatever you are writing in single quotes here will be printed as it is in the JS. You are printing `+` sign as it is here. Also you are using `id` inside PHP scope which should not be the case.

Comment: it gave me an jquery error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Try this : `$.post(\''.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(["death/stl_set_relation"]).'?id="+id+"&name="+id\')`

Comment: it redirected me to this link 192.168.1.4/~user/church/backend/web/death/stl_set_relation%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B?id=%22+id+%22&name=%22+id

Comment: use this: `$.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation']).'id="+id+"&name="+id)`

Comment: thanks for trying but i am afraid it did't work i got a url like this 192.168.1.4/~user/church/backend/web/death/stl_set_relationi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bd=22&name=22

Comment: Sorry. I missed one `?` . Try `$.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation']).'?id="+id+"&name="+id)`
. AND if that does not work then try `$.post("'.\Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['death/stl_set_relation']).'?id="+id+"&name="+id)`